# Load text from ANSI encrypted file into a RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am a beginner programmer and I am currently looking for a way to load texts from an ANSI encrypted file to a `RichTextBox` in my form. Also, I am looking for a way to save it back to the file with ANSI encryption.

This is what am I am currently trying:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Dim strResult As String
Using SR As StreamReader = New StreamReader("startup_config.cfg", Encoding.Default)
    strResult = SR.ReadToEnd
End Using
```

Comment: I'll add the code I am trying

Comment: Please read on Wikipedia about encryption and (character) encoding. These are very diffrent things in english language.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you mean ANSI *encoding* instead of *encrypted*.

You can use [`Encoding.GetEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.text.encoding.getencoding%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with one of the code pages from the list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead of using `Encoding.Default`. Here's the code sample from the `GetEncoding` page I linked above:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Namespace Convert_Example
  Class MyConvertExampleClass
    Shared Sub Main()
      Dim unicodeString As String = "This string contains the unicode character Pi(" & ChrW(&H03A0) & ")"

      ' Create two different encodings.
      Dim ascii As Encoding = Encoding.ASCII
      Dim [unicode] As Encoding = Encoding.Unicode

      ' Convert the string into a byte[].
      Dim unicodeBytes As Byte() = [unicode].GetBytes(unicodeString)

      ' Perform the conversion from one encoding to the other.
      Dim asciiBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Convert([unicode], ascii, unicodeBytes)

      ' Convert the new byte[] into a char[] and then into a string.
      ' This is a slightly different approach to converting to illustrate
      ' the use of GetCharCount/GetChars.
      Dim asciiChars(ascii.GetCharCount(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length)) As Char
      ascii.GetChars(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length, asciiChars, 0)
      Dim asciiString As New String(asciiChars)

      ' Display the strings created before and after the conversion.
      Console.WriteLine("Original string: {0}", unicodeString)
      Console.WriteLine("Ascii converted string: {0}", asciiString)
    End Sub
  End Class
End Namespace
```

To see if the code page you want is available, you can use [`GetEncodings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.text.encoding.getencodings%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get a list of them.

Comment: +1 for `GetEncodings`, I didn't knew about this method, but im afraid your code will scare beginner programmer.

Comment: @Kamil: The code sample is from the linked MSDN article; it's not mine. :-) If MS thinks it's a good sample, who am I to argue? :-) I don't think I've ever written more than a line or two of VB/VB.NET code in my life. I edited my answer to make sure it was clear the code came from that link target and wasn't written by me. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

ANSI encoding may mean any encoding.

`Encoding.Default` will return your default Code Page in Windows (it depends on regional settings in Windows, where program runs).

If file is encoded with other Code Page you have to set your StreamReader encoding to that Code Page, like this:

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(1250);
```

1250 is Central and East European Latin code page.

---

Added later:

You asked about saving back in that ANSI format - just use `StreamWriter` with same encoding as `StreamReader`.

Few code page examples and more about Code Pages at Wikipedia: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page)